# Dynamic templates in EJS (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Does anybody know a nice solution for including templates, whose names would be known only at run time? EJS's includes allows only to specify exact file/template name.

**Use case**: I have a article layout and there is article HTML/EJS content in some local file.

To do so I need something like https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs#includes but file name should be taken from locals variable:

Assume I have such handler (simplified):

```
app.get('/article/:article', function (req, res) {
        var articleContent = req.params.article;
        res.locals.articleContent = 'data/'+articleContent;
        return res.render('article.ejs')
    })
```

And in article.ejs (assume having ejs-locals):

```
<% layout('layout') -%>
<section>
  <article class="single-country">
      <% include ???articleContent???  %>
  </article>
</section>
```

Is there any possibility to do so or is the only option is to load article content and put into articleContent, so available by `<%- articleContent %>`?

The problem with this solution is that the content of article should be plain html (`<%- -%>' do not interpolate value). So if inside article I need to use any EJS feature, I need to compile/render by myself.

Maybe someone else already knows how this can be done with some dynamic include helper for EJS so no need of additional code?

Comment: I've edited your question as it was very hard to read. Please revert my changes if it changed the meaning. Also, what do you mean by `file name should be taken from variable.`? Do you have the content shared among multiple files? Also, I don't understand the whole `content of the article should be plain HTML` problem

Comment: Sorry... My thoughts were focused on finding solution. Changed text to be more understandable :)

Comment: AFAIK this is possible with EJS and express by employing the VM module, it felt messy to me and , as I was on the fence, between EJS and DUST, I went with DUST for a current project.
- here is a dynamic named partial 'included template file with DUST - {>"{dynamicvalue}.dust"/} . I hope there is a simpler answer for ejs as I like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Looks like this is now supported in EJ](https://github.com/mde/ejs#includes)S. It was introduced in [v2.0.1: 2015-01-02](https://github.com/mde/ejs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v201-2015-01-02). The new syntax looks like this

```
 <%- include(articleContent) %>
```

**To get this to work** I had to disable caching in Express by setting:

```
app.set('view cache', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter like this:

```
var ejs = require('ejs');
var fs = require('fs');

ejs.filters.article_teaser = function(my_object) {
    return ejs.render(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/views/' + my_object.template + '.ejs', 'utf8'), {my_object: my_object});
}
```

On your template just use:

```
<%-: article | article_teaser %>
```

Cheers!

Comment: Interesting workaround. But in this case from inner "render" parent scope/context would not be accessible... So it is like "isolated" rendering and not actual _include_...

Comment: EJS ^2.0.* supports this feature: Variable-based includes now possible