# EJS Template: Using forEach + include

Tags: node.js, ejs

I have many files in a Folder in want to include in a Template (EJS).

I try this:

```
 <% var test = ["foo.ejs"];
 _forEach(test, function(item){ %>
      <% include slides/item %>
  <% }); %>
```

I would use Nodejs to fill the Array by looking in a folder.

But i get the error:

```
 Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'app/views/slides/item.ejs'
```

It seems that ejs dont use "item" as a variable.

Comment: I don't think you can do it. Reading from ejs [code](https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs/blob/master/lib/ejs.js#L160), anything after 'include ' is treated as file template location

Comment: [Here you can find an answer to this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20775710/dynamic-templates-in-ejs-node-js)

Comment: There is a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20775710/dynamic-templates-in-ejs-node-js

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is now supported in [EJS](https://github.com/mde/ejs#includes). It was introduced in v2.0.1: 2015-01-02. The new syntax looks like this

**<%- include(yourVariable) %>**

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue for that problem in github.
https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs/issues/93