# How to place an EJS tag within another

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am using EJS as my templating engine. I am passing variables from node js to ejs like...

```
router.get("/AdminDatabase", function(req, res) {
    res.render('Pages/AdminDatabase', {title: 'WebFormsAdmin', role: 'System Admin' });
  });
```

I am building a role base control and for this I want to change the header of the page base on the role of user.

```
<% include ../partials/Common/header_<%= role %> %>
```

The problem is with the above segment. How can I place the variable **role** inside this EJS code segment?

My header files are

header_System Admin.ejs,

header_Survey Admin.ejs,

header_Survey Taker.ejs

Comment: you can check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20775710/dynamic-templates-in-ejs-node-js

Comment: I could not find exactly what I needed. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround would be to do a conditional render like so:

```
<% switch (role) {
  case 'System Admin': %>
    <% include ./partials/header_System_Admin %>
    <% break; %>
  <% case 'Survey Admin': %>
    <% include ./partials/header_Survey_Admin %>
    <% break; %>
  <% default: %>
    <% include ./partials/header_Survey_Taker %>
    <% break; %>
<% } %>
```

Note that the first case must be grouped with the switch declaration. Make sure the paths are correct for your partials.

Comment: I am passing the role from node js as stated above. How can I include that here? Is it like this??     <% switch (<%= role %>) {

Comment: @K.Kabilesh The `role` variable is exactly what's being evaluated in the switch statement. You don't have to render it.

Comment: For an example I showed that as    role: 'System Admin'. But I am passing the role from a cookie.     role: req.cookies.role...It is dynamically determined when the user logs in

Comment: In your original post, you showed that the `role` was being passed in from the route. This is how you would work with a variable passed into a template in that way. You should determine authorization levels on the server side, anyway.

Comment: Can you help me with this question also?  It is related to ejs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42734396/error-while-sending-parameters-to-ejs-page-from-node-js

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the path and the variable.

```js
<%- include('../partials/Common/header_'+role) %>
```