# Error while sending parameters to EJS page from node js

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am sending parameters from node js to an EJS page as...

```
router.get("/AdminDatabase", function(req, res) {
   res.render('Pages/AdminDatabase', { title: 'WebFormsAdmin', role:  req.cookies.role  });
 });
```

How can I do the same in the below code..

```
router.get('/CreateSurvey', function(req, res, next) {

  var Education = QBank.findOne({_id:"id1"});
  var Political = QBank.findOne({_id:"id2"});

  var resources = {
    education: Education.exec.bind(Education),
    political: Political.exec.bind(Political)
  };

  async.parallel(resources, function (error, results){
    if (error) {
        res.status(500).send(error);
        return;
    }
    res.render('Pages/CreateSurvey', results);
   });

 });
```

I tried this as below, but that gives me some error. The page is not rendering. It says error.. failed to look in view. 
Can anyone help in this?

```
   res.render('Pages/CreateSurvey', {results: results, title: 'WebFormsAdmin', role:  req.cookies.role  });
```

I think the problem is the way I pass the parameters here. The **results** is the problem here

Comment: Define _"some error"_.

Comment: The page is not rendering. It says error.. failed to look in view